# gvim regexp for nested parentheses

Tags: regex, vim

I have file containing abc(de+fgh(2a+2b))+xyz(). i want to write regexp(preferably vim) to get a pattern like de+fgh(2a+2b) + xyz() .

I tried in gvim regexp But while matching parenthesis, if i use **greedy** option it will match  abc(de+fgh(2a+2b))+xyz(**)** and for **non-greedy** option it will matching with abc(de+fgh(2a+2b')')+xyz() , how to match with abc(de+fgh(2a+2b)')'+xyz().

Regards
keerthan

Comment: Vim regular expressions aren’t able to match arbitrary parenthesis nestings. Vim itself can, though, and Perl regular expressions can too. How are you going to be using the result?

Comment: thanks you for showing Interest , i have file containing such patterns, so i want to replace that patterns                                                                               would be great if u could direct me if direct me in perl regexp

Answer (score 1):

I won't do it with regex, assume that your cursor is at BOL, just do:

```
%di(v0p
```

you will get desired output.

Translating it into english, take the stuff between first `(..)` group and concatenate it with whatever after the first `(...)` group.

You can use `:normal` cmd or macro to apply the operations on multiple lines.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response, I couldn't understand , are u taking in vim ?

Answer (score 0):

Watch out! regex cannot handle counting arbitrary numbers of brackets. If you want to do this generally, you might need to write a parser.

That said, if you only need this to work for a specific case:
http://regexr.com/3fne0

in vim this is:

```
%s/[^()]*(\([^()]*([^()]*)\))\(.*\)/\1\2/g
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for respose .. No, in my file there are many cases are there so i want generalized solution. any language regex also file . Just need solution

Comment: If you want a general solution, you're going to need to write a parser. A regex cannot count the number of brackets for you and so cannot balance the brackets.